# Adding Colspan in PagerStyle of DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

How to add colspan in the pagerstyle of the data grid.
Because after binding userdetails (having two columns-ID and Name) are showing perfect 
but the pager is srinked to the 1st column itself not expended to the page width.

Tried with setting width 100% or 100px but dint work.
When i tried setting  colspan(it was showing 1) as 2 from IE's developer tool, its rendered perfectly.

PS: it was working fine in .net 1.1 but project is now converted into 4.0

Sample code:

```
<div id="divMS" class="bodytext8pt" style="overflow-Y: auto; overflow-X: hidden; width: expression(document.body.clientWidth); height: expression((document.getElementById('divPageHeader') ? document.body.clientHeight-parseInt(document.getElementById('divPageHeader').style.height)-45 : document.body.clientHeight-45)); border: black solid 1px">
    <asp:datagrid id="dgResults" CellPadding="3" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" Width="100%" Height="1"
        runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="GridAltItem" Height="20"></AlternatingItemStyle>
        <ItemStyle CssClass="GridItem" Height="20"></ItemStyle>
        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" CssClass="GridHeader DataGridFixedHeader" Height="20"></HeaderStyle>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateColumn>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox id="chkMSAll" OnCheckedChanged="chk_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" Width="20"></asp:CheckBox>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox id="chkMSItem" runat="server" Width="20"></asp:CheckBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
        <PagerStyle CssClass="GridItem hoverLinkHover" Mode="NumericPages" Height="20" wrap="false"></PagerStyle>
    </asp:datagrid>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed the method mentioned in the page:
http://www.softwarecodehelp.com/2009/08/11/PagingColspanProblemInDatagridASPNet11.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" PageSize="3">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fname (Age)" SortExpression="fname">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fname") %>'></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;(<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Age") %>'></asp:Label>
                )
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
      SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblA]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

[image]

Comment: You can use GridView and SqlDataSource instead of datagrid.

Comment: Ok.. i'll try.. but is there any way to add colspan in pagerstyle from codebehind?